# rpi v/s carambola --- rootfile system size

Tags: raspberry-pi, openwrt

I am using following distribution for raspberry pi.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads
http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/images/raspbian/2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbian/2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbian.zip

FOR rpi It is recommended to use >2GB card.

Also when i install it on my memory card size of root file system is about 1.4GB.
But dont you think it is too much size just for an root filesystem in **EMBEDDED SYSTEM**.

Is it possible for **RPI** to make a linux distribution with root file system with small size ?

Because most of the embedded system do not have this much memory.
like **carambola** have **8mb Flash & 32 MB RAM**.
http://8devices.com/carambola

In this case carambola root filesystem (OPEN wrt) will fit in 8MB flash. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian is a full on general purpose operating system, with the ability to run X windows, create a development environment, watch movies, play games, etc.

It also includes support for a great many devices you might want to connect via USB, such as networking devices, webcams, keyboards, mice, etc.

Many embedded systems are purpose built, with no options for adding/removing devices, nor options for running arbitrary programs.  OpenWRT is a routing platform running on typical router hardware, and as such, can be MUCH smaller.

Comment: I haven't come across anyone who has done so, but conceptually there is no reason why it wouldn't work.  However, there's also no real compelling reason to do so.  There is no on board flash and the device is set up to boot from the SD card.  SD's are pretty cheap, you can get an 8G Class 10 for under 10 dollars at Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) for this, which also has been the base of OpenWrt (OpenWrt used for creating the rootfs for the linked Carambola). Buildroot also has support for raspberry pi, so you can easily create a pretty small rootfs with just a few of installed packages.